# Why can't MATLAB deploytool output exe file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

`deploytool` works well until creating exe file using mbuild then get this error:

```
Executing command: mbuild  -O -v -output "U1" -I"e:\Mat2009\work\ntst1\U1\src" "e:\Mat2009\work\ntst1\U1\src\U1_main.c" "e:\Mat2009\work\ntst1\U1\src\U1_delay_load.c" "e:\Mat2009\work\ntst1\U1\src\U1_mcc_component_data.c" -link exe  -env MCR_DELAYLOAD=/delayload:mclmcrrt710.dll -env 
MCR_DELAYLIB=delayimp.lib -outdir "e:\Mat2009\work\ntst1\U1\src" 

Error: An error occurred while shelling out to mbuild (error code = -1). 

Unable to build executable. 

??? Error using ==> mcc
Error executing mcc, return status = 1 (0x1).
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: are you using vb? i reinstalled it and it worked fine then..

Answer (score 0):

This error looks similar to an error I encountered once (after upgrading to 2012b), I cannot recall the source but I found two potential solutions:

1. Make sure there are no spaces in the path to the compiler
2. Try building a few times and cross your fingers

Given the time frame I had I chose to go for option two and after 5-10 attempts it suprisingly worked.

Answer (score 0):

***have found that COMSPEC env. var had a wrong value, so I deleted the wrong path, restarted MATLAB then it worked well.***

Comment: Could you please expand your answer a bit to help future visitors?